# Chef return out of recipe depending on bash command output

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Is there a way in Chef to return out of a recipe based on the output of a bash command?

I tried the following:

```
execute 'check_output' do
  command <<-EOH
    output=$(echo "hi")
    if [ "$output" == "hi" ]; then
        return 0
    fi
  EOH
end

include_recipe 'blahblah::default'
```

I'd like to stop the entire Chef recipe with an exit code of 0 and not hit the `include_recipe` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really the way you have written it, because the properties of the `execute` resource won't be considered until convergence time, which is after the recipe `blablah::default` has been included. You can't decide whether to include another recipe during convergence time.

To do what you want, whatever shell stuff you want to do has to be decidable at compile time, such as:

`` include_recipe 'blahblah::default' unless `echo -n "hi"` == 'hi' ``

which would result in the recipe's not being included.

See coderanger's good description of Chef's two-pass model here: https://coderanger.net/two-pass/

To apply that to what you want to do, you have to decide whether to get `include_recipe` during compile time, not during converge time.